# Convert Java SE application to java web app {netbeans}

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, web

I was trying to learn java and I did so by doing a simple Java SE application with a MySQL database, everything works fine. Now I need to put all of this on a tomcat server to have a web app, what is the most reliable way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a Java SE to Java Web App

1. Right click on the project properties. Select "Project Facets", and
   click "convert to faceted form…"
2. Check "Dynamic Web Module" and "Java", and specify the value.
3. Eclipse will generate all "web" related files (like
   WEB-INF, web.xml) in a "WebContent" folder. If you want change it to
   another location, Clicks on the "further configuration available…"
   link.
4. Write Your Servlet class

Comment: I am doing this on netbeans, sorry forgot to mention that but I will look if there is similar steps for netbeans. Thank you !

Comment: @EssamGouda Did you find a netbeans solution ?

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa not really but there is some work arounds like running a java application when a certain URL is requested by the user but what I actually learned here is to always make the choice earlier in development stage whether I need a web app or desktop app.